# using vb dll in .net core 3.1 project

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have  a.net core 3.1 Web API project and I have to use functions from a dll programmed in vb.
and I am not allowed to modify the dll.
when running the service,I get the error:
"Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fghda'.",

I tried addind this dll in .netframework web API project and by adding "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" nuget to the references ,I could successfully run the service.
the problem is this nuget is not working in .net core and using similiar nugets were useless.
I also added microsoft.visualbasic dll but nothing changed.
So anybody knows how to resolve the issue?

Comment: "have to use functions"... can you at least write a companion exe in the same tech stack (vb.net) to call those functions, and do the .net core <> vb.net communication via command line, files, or something else?

Comment: Is the VB.NET DLL targeting the .NET Framework? Then you are out of luck and will not be able to use it from .NET Core.

Comment: I mentioned that I used these dlls in another .netframework webapi project and the problem is using them in .net core. and I have also used them in a vb.net webform project too.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core still does not seem to support VB .NET. It was mentioned in the previous statement that it will be supported in the future.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-in-net-core-3-0/